# Permutation test of meta-analysis : correlation coefficient

Tags: r, correlation, permutation-test, false-discovery-rate

I am going to estimate False Discovery Rate using permutation tests.

To my knowledge, several R packages are applicable for multiple testing.

I have several independent datasets for meta-analysis.

I computed a Pearson correlation coefficient, converted it into a Fisher-Z score and then calculated the mean effect size of each gene pair from several independent datasets.

Actually, in each dataset, there are two different subgroups - healthy subjects and patients. In this co-expression network, I analyzed the gene expression profiles of the *patient* group only.

Here is my question.

> What should I do to estimate FDR using permutation test with creating random and independent shuffling gene expression values of all genes in each dataset
>   to break the inter-gene relationships while keeping intact the expression mean and standard deviation of the genes in every dataset?

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it. I am still new to statistics and as well as R.

I would appreciate it if you could answer the question with corresponding code I could run.